# Select no NODE retorna vazio

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, oracle

Quando executo essa query:

```
SELECT xml_nfe FROM NDD_COLD.COLD_PROD WHERE ide_id ='NFe42200602831172001104550000010390091233318028'
```

No plsql ele me retorna uma linha com informações, ai passo a mesma query no nodejs dessa forma:

```
const dbConfig = require("./conexaoDBoracle.js");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

class ConsultaXML {
async consultaXML() {

let connection;

try {

  connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig)

  let result = connection.execute(`SELECT xml_nfe FROM NDD_COLD.COLD_PROD WHERE ide_id ='NFe42200602831172001104550000010390091233318028'`);

  console.log((await result))
  return (await result).rows;

} catch (err) {

  console.error(err);
}
}
}
module.exports = new ConsultaXML;
```

e ele me retorn isto:

```
{ metaData: [ { name: 'XML_NFE' } ], rows: [] }
```

Alguem tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Voce chegou a tentar fazer essa query usando o `bind` pro `ide_id`?

Comment: apos a minha conexão adicionei o seguinte:
oracledb.fetchAsString = [oracledb.CLOB]

e o retorno do método assim:

const clob = (await result).rows[0][0];
return clob

Por causa do tamanho do retorno da query, conforme manual da oracle:

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/node-oracledb-112:-working-with-lobs-as-string-and-buffer-connection-pinging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, devido ao retorno da query ser muito extenso precisei fazer o seguinte

```
const dbConfig = require("./conexaoDBoracle.js");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

class ConsultaXML {

async consultaXML(chave) {


let connection;


try {

  connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig)

  oracledb.fetchAsString = [oracledb.CLOB]

  let result = connection.execute(`SELECT XML_NFE AS XML
  FROM NDD_COLD.COLD_ENTR 
  WHERE IDE_ID = '${chave}'
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT XML_NFE AS XML
  FROM NDD_COLD.COLD_PROD 
  WHERE IDE_ID = '${chave}'`);
  
  
  const clob = (await result).rows[0][0];

  
  return clob
  
} catch (err) {

  console.error(err);
}
}
}
module.exports = new ConsultaXML;
```